# Инвертирование массива

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Помогите выполнить задание, ломаю голову уже 2й час.

Определите и реализуйте общий статический метод `invert`, который возвращает инвертированную версию входного массива. Вы можете инвертировать массив на месте во входном массиве.

```
Sample Input 1:
Integer
10 6 2 3
Sample Output 1:
3 2 6 10
```

Мой код:

```
class ArrayUtils {
    public static <T> T invert(T[] array) {
        return reverse(array);
    }

    public static <T> T reverse(T[] names) {
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(names));
        return (T) names;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно свой компаратор написать, чтоб массив инвертировать:

```java
Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{10, 6, 2, 3};
Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> -1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [3, 2, 6, 10]
```

Или циклом можно обработать как массив объектов, так и массив примитивов:

```java
int[] arr = new int[]{10, 6, 2, 3};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
    arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [3, 2, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете список на лету и тут же "теряете" его после отработки `Collections.reverse()`

```
public static <T> T reverse(T[] names) {
    List<T> list = Arrays.asList(names);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    return Arrays.toArray(list);
}
```

Comment: Все те же ошибки(

Main.java:50: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                array = ArrayUtils.invert(array);
                                         ^
    lower bounds: Short[],Object
    lower bounds: Short
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>invert(T[])

Comment: Main.java:42: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                array = ArrayUtils.invert(array);
                                         ^
    lower bounds: Long[],Object
    lower bounds: Long
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>invert(T[])

Comment: Main.java:34: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                array = ArrayUtils.invert(array);
                                         ^
    lower bounds: String[],Object
    lower bounds: String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>invert(T[])

Comment: Main.java:26: error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                array = ArrayUtils.invert(array);
                                         ^
    lower bounds: Integer[],Object
    lower bounds: Integer
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>invert(T[])

Comment: Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        return Arrays.toArray(list);
                     ^
  symbol:   method toArray(List<T>)
  location: class Arrays
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>invert(T[])

Comment: @Rudione цель состоит не том, чтобы за вас все решить, а наметить путь ее решения. Я не компилятор и не пишу текст в IDE и не проверяю его. Дальше уже сами - удачи.